# "script time out" when using protractor (there is a referenced third-party resources(google map) that takes too long to load)

Tags: protractor

I am a fresh Protractor user trying to write some Protractor E2E test.

The page I am testing has some TextInput boxes, and a app-map(google map).
When I tried to enter some charactors by using "sendkeys" function, the script failed with the error "script time out".

I assumed that it took too long for protractor to load the entire page. 
For this page I just want to find the textbox elements and enter some charactors. Could anyone help me to igore the loading of the google map?

best regards
shixiang

Comment: hard to guess without seeing the code, try to attach it to your question

Comment: thank you! I tried waitForAngularEnabled(false), and it works!

Answer (score 0):

1. Set `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false)` in your script file this ignores the wait time to load the components.
2. Use **expected conditions** to make your script wait till the text boxes appear. here is the link for more info on expected conditions

https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions

3. Add **allScriptsTimeout** in your config file which will override jasmine default timeout("allScriptsTimeout: 2400000"). You can set the timeout value depending on your requirement. it's in millisec.
   Hope this helps

Comment: thank you! I tried waitForAngularEnabled(false) and it works!